# Regex - find string which does not contain certain char

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a way to write regex which match any 5 digit numbers in string, except those, which are followed by slash.

I can't figure out why this RE doesn't work:

```
r"\D(\d{%d})[^/]\D" % 5
```

EXAMPLE

```
'dsadasd894665' -> NO MATCH
'dsadsa78954,4' -> 78954 
'dsda78954/sdd' -> NO MATCH
```

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<!\d)(\d{5})(?!\/|\d)
```

Try this.This Works.See demo.Your regex does not start or end with 0 width assertions.So it actually needs 1 charcter before and 2 ahead.

http://regex101.com/r/yA5iD9/16

Comment: @vks Exactly. `12345` is a 5 digit string in `123456`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?<!\d)\d{5}(?=[^\d/]|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fG1vD4/3)

**EXplanation:**

- `(?<!\d)` Match wouldn't be preceded by a digit.
- `\d{5}` Exactly 5 digits.
- `(?=[^\d/]|$)` Must be followed by a  non-digit or `/` or end of the line anchor.

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> s1 = "dsadasd894665"
>>> s2 = "dsadsa78954,4"
>>> s3 = "dsda78954/sdd"
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\d)\d{5}(?=[^\d/]|$)', s1)
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\d)\d{5}(?=[^\d/]|$)', s2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f0835855370>
>>> re.search(r'(?<!\d)\d{5}(?=[^\d/]|$)', s3)
```

Comment: instead of using this kind of alternation in a lookaround, use a negative lookaround: `(?<!\d)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your regex is not working is due to the `\D`s. I don't know why you put them in. Another problem is that `[^/]` will not match the end of the string, so use `?!` instead.

The following works:

```
r"(\d{%d})(?!\/)" % 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to find numbers that are on their own, i.e. not preceeded by another number, not followed by another number, and also not followed by a slash, we are going to use [negative look-aheads and look-behinds](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) to ensure this:

```
(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!/|\d)
```

This will match a `\d{5}` if it is *not* preceeded by another `\d` (i.e. no number is before it), and it is also *not* followed by another `\d` or a `/`.

Using that on your examples yields the desired results:

```
>>> for example in ('dsadasd894665', 'dsadsa78954,4', 'dsda78954/sdd'):
    print(re.search(r'(?<!\d)\d{%d}(?!/|\d)' % 5, example))

None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 11), match='78954'>
None
```